# continuously changing array size

Tags: java, android

I have an array of strings but the values in array is changing continuously. 
Is there any other way of managing the array except removing items and changing index locations?

```
   public String[] deviceId=null; 
   deviceId=new String[deviceCount];
```

in my case deviceCount is changes as new device comes. 
so i continuously need to change array size and add or remove items

Comment: Is it a requirement that you have to use arrays. If not use `dynamic arrays` or `linked lists`

Comment: i prefer to use arrayList

Comment: learn about ArrayList and other collection objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ArrayList in place of String[] ..
And you can also easily cast ArrayList to String[] for your final output as

```
ArrayList<String>  mStringList= new ArrayList<String>();
mStringList.add("ann");
mStringList.add("john");
String[] mStringArray = new String[mStringList.size()];
mStringArray = mStringList.toArray(mStringArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a List. It changes size depending on how many objects you put in it.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
public static void main(String[] args) {
     list.add("string 1"); //Add strings to the list
     list.add("string 2");
     System.out.println(list.get(0)); //Get the values from the list
     System.out.println(list.get(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Arrays, you could use ArrayLists. You can add as much as you want to them without having to re-size the array and once you no longer need an item it can be removed. Here is a link to an overview of ArrayLists and some examples using them: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the max count of devices. Then  you can define an array with max size.

```
String[]  deviceId = new String[MAX_DEVICE_COUNT];
```

Or else simply go with a List.

```
List<String>  deviceId=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Don't worry about performance, so much with a array.

Answer (score 0):

**-** In Java arrays are `initialized` at the time of its creation whether its `declared` at class level or at local level.

**-** Once the size is defined of an `array in Java it can't be changed`.

**-** Its better to use Collection like List.

**-** It has the flexibility to add and delete the items in it, and one can also at items at desired location in the List.

**-** List is an `Interface` in Java, you can use its `concrete sub classes` like ArrayList, LinkedList..etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether i got the question correctly but you can use ArrayList or LinkedList if the size is going to change dynamically.